# Calling a templatized std::function stored in a map

Tags: c++, linux, stl, variadic-templates, c++17

I'm attempting to create a base class that will store signals (in the form of an `int`) and allow me to later use them to call functions specified by the derived class. They are stored in an `unordered_map` because it's exactly what I need -- 1 signal = 1 function (plus it's fast).

Though, I'm having some trouble calling them, getting a huge error in the form of:

> no match for call to ‘(`std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void()>, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::function<void()> > > >::mapped_type` {aka `std::function<void()>`}) `(int&, int&)`’

The compile-error is from `signals_[_sig](args...);`

```
const int SIGCHANGE = 1;

template<typename... Args>
class Signal {
private:
  std::unordered_map< int, std::function<void(Args...)> > signals_;

  inline void SetSignal(const int& _sig, std::function<void(Args...)> _func) {
    signals_[_sig] = _func;
  }

public:
  Signal() {}
  ~Signal() {}

  template<typename... Ts>
  void Sig(const int& _sig, Ts... args) {
    if (signals_.find(_sig) != signals_.end()) {
      signals_[_sig](args...);
    }
  }
};

class Obj : public Signal<> { 
private:
  int num_;

public:
  Obj* child;

  void Change(int _num) {
    num_ = _num;
    child->Sig(SIGCHANGE, _num);
  }

  void HandleChanged(int _num) {
    num_ = _num;
  }

};

int main() {
  Obj* obj1 = new Obj();
  Obj* obj2 = new Obj();

  obj1->child = obj2;

  obj1->Change(10);
}
```

Also, I have no idea if I'm using the templates correctly - it's been ages since I last used them. Should each function have its own template? Why do I have to specify the template before the class if I want to use it for a member variable?

Comment: Well, apparently the function to call (at least in the template) is typed `void func()`  (without any parameters) and you call the `Sig` with two int parameters, that of course can't work. In particular, using `template<typename... Ts>` is useless, you can only have the same parameters as the whole `Signal` template, so the function can (and should) be `void Sig(const int& _sig, Args... args)`, as with any other set of parameters it will not work anyway.

Comment: Please post an MCVE. Your code is taken out of context and you leave us guessing as to how to reproduce the compilation error.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Sorry, forgot that the call was somewhere else, I'll add it in.

Comment: @areuz: If you want to be extra nice to future readers, then add a `main` function and the missing `#include`s, and remove the clearly unnecessary stuff, e.g. the constructor, the destructor and the constants :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yep, of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you function has a single `int` parameter, you need to have

```
class Obj : public Signal<int>
```

instead of

```
class Obj : public Signal<>
```

The later creates a map with functions prototyped `void()`, whereas you need a function prototyped `void(int)`.

Also, templatizing the `Sig` function is useless, because you will not be able to call it with any other set of parameters than `Args` anyway. So it can simply be

```
  void Sig(const int& _sig, Args... args) {
    if (signals_.find(_sig) != signals_.end()) {
      signals_[_sig](args...);
    }
  }
```

If your goal is to support storing functions with arbitrary prototype, that does need to be done different way, basically via runtime polymorphism (all the items in the map need to be of the same type, so the type itself would need to do the call polymorphism under the hood).

---

### EDIT

One possibility with function prototypes defined according to the signal type. Requires that the signal ints will always be passed as compile-time constants - the different functor for particular signal types are stored in `std::tuple`:

```
const int SIGZERO = 0;
const int SIGCHANGE = 1;
const int SIGOTHER = 2;

// non-specialized template intentionally left empty
// (or can provide default prototype)
template<int SIG>
struct SignalPrototype;

template<>
struct SignalPrototype<SIGZERO>
{
    typedef std::function< void() > type;
};

template<>
struct SignalPrototype<SIGCHANGE>
{
    typedef std::function< void(int) > type;
};

template<>
struct SignalPrototype<SIGOTHER>
{
    typedef std::function< void(int, int) > type;
};


class Signal {
private:
    std::tuple<
        SignalPrototype<SIGZERO>::type,
        SignalPrototype<SIGCHANGE>::type,
        SignalPrototype<SIGOTHER>::type
    > signals_;

protected:

    template<int SIG>
    inline void SetSignal(typename SignalPrototype<SIG>::type _func) {
        std::get<SIG>(signals_) = _func;
    }

public:

    template<int SIG, typename... Ts>
    void Sig(Ts... args) {
        SignalPrototype<SIG>::type func = std::get<SIG>(signals_);
        if (func)
            func(args...);
    }

};

struct MyHandler : SignalPrototype<SIGCHANGE>::type
{
    void operator()(int x)
    {
        std::cout << "Called MyHandler with x = " << x << std::endl;
    }
};


class Obj : public Signal {
private:
    int num_;

public:
    Obj* child;

    Obj()
    {
        SetSignal<SIGCHANGE>(MyHandler());
    }

    void Change(int _num) {
        num_ = _num;
        child->Sig<SIGZERO>();
        child->Sig<SIGCHANGE>(_num);
        child->Sig<SIGOTHER>(1, 2);
    }

    void HandleChanged(int _num) {
        num_ = _num;
    }

};
```

(and in general, it could be actually better for Signal to be member of the Obj instead of inheritance)

Comment: Hmm. I see. I was using the templates incorrectly. What I want to achieve is a homogeneous container of different function templates.

Comment: Oops, didn't see your edit, yes, that is what I want to achieve... So is that not possible with templates? Hmm... Is it possible to use Lambdas?

Comment: @areuz: Your `Signal` template is a mechanism to create many different containers, e.g. `Signal<int>`, `Signal<double, float>` and `Signal<std::string, int, int>`. It does not result in *one* homogeneous container. Variadic templates are still a compile-time mechanism.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yeah, but what should I use then (googling 'runtime polymorphism' didn't really yield much)? I think I remember that a long time ago I did this with lambdas, but it was pretty ugly.

Comment: Well, with polymorphic store it is tricky, one part is how to store it (easier), and the other part is how to correctly call it (the tricky part). I'm trying in my test if I'll be able to figure out how to do that, but as said it's tricky :)

Comment: @areuz: The question is: Where do you get your arguments from? At some point, a signal arrives. Choosing the correct function for a given signal is easy, but now you need to **call** the function, so you need to pass arguments. This is the point where you must somehow commit to a particular instantation of a template. You cannot magically create a catch-it-all abstraction for "call anything with any parameters and still be type-safe". Here's an idea: Invert the control flow. Make your map's value type `std::function<void>` and have every function get its conceptual arguments.

Comment: @ChristianHackl By "have every function get its conceptual arguments" you mean that, when the function is being added into the map, it already has the argument types defined? That could work, I'll have to look into how to do it though.

Comment: @areuz: No, actually I mean that technically, the functions have *no* arguments, but their implementations actively get all necessary data to perform their work. So they are just conceptual arguments. `void f() { int const my_arg = get_data_from_somewhere(); /* ... */ }`

Comment: @ChristianHackl Ohh, but that isn't possible in my case. If you look at the `void Change(int _num)` function, you see that `->Sig(....)` is getting copies of local variables. Because after that function ends, noone knows what changed. It's just a snippet, but this is also true in my full code.

Comment: @areuz: Well, you could change your architecture such that the values contained in the local variables are accessible to the functions. But it's just an idea. As you can see, it's really more of a big-picture question (compile time vs. runtime) and not something you can work around with a few lines of code. Another idea would be to use `std::variant` / `boost::variant` as the parameter type of every function.

Comment: Yes, this thing is basically leading to "double dispatch", which is kinda difficult in C++ even with runtime polymorphism (possibly we could get around that with dynamic_cast, but it has quite big runtime costs).

Comment: Could it be that a single type of signal would have a single function prototype? I.e.: would `SIGCHANGE` always have prototype `void(int)`? In that case it might be doable by templatizing upon the signal type.

Comment: @axalis Yes.. and no... That is possible, but SIGCHANGE isn't a unique type but a simple int - for specifying the signal type, so I don't know how that would work.

Comment: Well, you can actually templatize and specialize on (constant) int parameter (anyway, the function prototype would probably need to be consistent between setting and calling for the particular signal).